Swift Combine is leaking when using API subscribe<S>(_ subject: S) -> AnyCancellable
Example code:
class SwiftViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let subject1 = PassthroughSubject<(), Never>().eraseToAnyPublisher()
        let subject2 = PassthroughSubject<(), Never>()
        self.cancellable = subject1.subscribe(subject2)
    }
}


Push to SwiftViewController and go back. SwiftViewController things will be released.
The leaking is

I am using Xcode 15.2, iOS simulator 17.4
There is a similar question Is Combines Publisher.subscribe(_ subject) leaking sometimes?

Have you cancelled the subscription, or destroyed the view controller, at the point that the lead is reported?

@ScottThompson Yes. The view controller is released.

I guess it's a bug of Combine. This is a workaround
extension Publisher {

    public func subscribe<S>(_ subject: S) -> AnyCancellable where S : Subject, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Output {
        return self.sink { completion in
            subject.send(completion: completion)
        } receiveValue: { value in
            subject.send(value)
        }

    }
}

We override the system API and use sink to implement it again. The bug is gone in my case.
